# Advice on copper pours

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-layers

Below are the pictures I have of the PCB design of the sepic converter using LT3958 (datasheet [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3958fa.pdf)).

1. I used a polygon to connect the GNDS of the IC and output capacitors. Since I have another polygon near for Switching pins the ground polygon does not surround the pins completely (See the 3D view for better understanding). Will this cause any issues?
2. Another point I want some clarification on is having both power and ground planes at the bottom side. (See pic 3 for this)Will this lead to any parasitic capacitance? Currently, I have 72V pour as rank 2 with Isolate as 10. Should I increase the isolate value?

Thank you, anyone, for the help in advance.

[image: LT3958-sepic connection pcb]
[image]

[image: power and ground pour]

Comment: A copper pour on the switching node sounds like a bad idea to me. I also note that you seem to be trying to maintain isolation between your 72 V and ground pours, but then you have them right up next to each other near the pin on the left and where the 72 V pour goes vertical on the right. Might want to fix that, otherwise your attempts at isolation are useless.

Comment: Copper pour on SW nodes was in the recommended layout in the datasheet and I see no issue with it. I will inc the distance b/w the 72V and GND vias. My main concern is that pad is not being surrounded completely by the copper pour due to the adjacent pour.

Answer (score 1):

1. The best advice I can offer here is to copy the layout pictured in the datasheet (page 23).  Do your best to copy that.  Also, read all the layout advice on this page carefully.  These guys know what they are talking about.
2. It is not an issue to have these on the same layer.  Parasitic capacitance will be minimal. (Capacitance is more of an issue having overlapping shapes on adjacent layers).  Also, any parasitic capacitance here would be drowned out by the actual capacitors in the circuit.  I recommend these 2 potentials are separated by no less than 1.5mm, and cover with soldermask.  This is a rule of thumb I use for low voltage power traces and is based on IPC2221 recommendations with some extra margin.